# Can't send mail from server using sendmail/postfix; 'connecion timed out'

Tags: postfix

I can't send mail via my server.
The mails get stuck in the mail qeueu.

How can I fix this?

`mailq`:

```
74226301703      850 Fri Mar 23 17:35:44  web6@server28.example.com
(connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.77.26]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         ************@gmail.com

7097B301265      850 Fri Mar 23 17:10:50  web6@server28.example.com
(connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.77.27]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         ************@gmail.com

3EDE13016DE      856 Fri Mar 23 17:09:03  web6@server28.example.com
(connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.77.26]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         ************@gmail.com
```

`telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`:

```
Trying 173.194.77.26...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Is this on a home system?  Many residential ISPs block `tcp/25` for fear of botnets.

Comment: Yes, is on a home system. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Setup you email server to use the ISP SMTP server as relay host. Usually, they should allow you to send over port 25 to their email server only.
2. Use an external email server running (like gmail). This server can be accessed on port other than 25.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to set up a smart host or place your server somewhere else.
Also if it's only for use from only one account, you can use something like msmtp, that can send your email through another mail account.